# Getting into stored procedures, need help converting a query

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I never used stored procedures, but I faced a reality when I need to move my query to server. Please assist.

This is my function that I created via PHP:

```
function getResults($userid) {
        $query = "select * from myTable where iduser= ?";
        $stmt = $this->openDb()->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $rows;
    }
```

I never used stored procedures and not sure how to approach:

1. How do I add this as stored procedure to MySQL, so I could submit
   one integer variable to it
2. How do I `prepare' the integer variable that I will submit to stored procedure
3. How do I retrieve the result set from stored procedure back to php
   function.

If you could assist, I will review your solution and will be able to continue on my own.

I checked google and I see that to create a stored procedure I need to start like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getResults` (IN userid INT)  
BEGIN  

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MYSQL:**

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getResults$$

CREATE PROCEDURE getResults(IN I_USERID INT(10))
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE iduser = I_USERID;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**PHP:**

```
$sql = "CALL getResults(?)";
$stmt = $this->openDb()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($userid));

while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
    //use fields like this: $row->fieldname1, $row->fieldname2...
}
$stmt->closeCursor();
```

On a side note, I would recommend naming explicitely your fields instead of using the `*` selector in your query.

Hope it helps,
S.